# Using REGEXP_EXTRACT extract 7 digit numbers

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I have one requirement.I want to extract 7 digit numbers from one of the column and lookup with another table get another column for each 7 digit number and concatenate with "|".

**Column Data:** In this need to extract 7 digit numbers. 
";2435034;1;5.98;;eVar36=bopis|ev2=2605,;1483528;1;17.97;;ev6=bopis|evar52=2605,;1010203;1;7.98;;ev6=bopis|ev2=2605"

**Output(Extract 7 digit number):**

```
 2435034,1483528,1010203
```

**Another table:**

```
account name
2435034 D1
1483528 D2
1010203 D3
```

**Final output is(after joining with another table):**

```
     account_nbr        account_name
2435034|1483528|1010203  D1|D2|D3
```

I tried with the following command to extract 7 digit number. I was getting only first number, remaining number are not coming.

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(REGEXP_REPLACE(";2435034;1;5.98;;eVar36=bopis|ev2=2605,;1483528;1;17.97;;ev6=bopis|evar52=2605,;1010203;1;7.98;;ev6=bopis|ev2=2605", r'[^\d]+', ','),r'[0-9]+')
```

This might be simple but not able to figure it out. Tried with GROUP_CONCAT and SPLIT function also getting following error.

```
Exactly one capturing group must be specified
```

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try replacing `r'[0-9]+'` with `r'([0-9]+)'`. Besides, `r'[^\d]+'` can be written as `r'\D+'`

Comment: You probably need to use REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL using standard SQL instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  STRING_AGG(nbr, '|' ORDER BY pos) account_nbr,
  STRING_AGG(name, '|' ORDER BY pos) account_name,  
  data
FROM `project.dataset.yourTable` t, 
UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(REGEXP_REPLACE(t.data, r'[^\d]+', ','),r'[0-9]{7}')) nbr WITH OFFSET pos
JOIN `project.dataset.anotherTable` x
ON CAST(x.account AS STRING) = nbr
GROUP BY data
```

You can test / play with it using dummy data from your question:

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.yourTable` AS (
  SELECT ";2435034;1;5.98;;eVar36=bopis|ev2=2605,;1483528;1;17.97;;ev6=bopis|evar52=2605,;1010203;1;7.98;;ev6=bopis|ev2=2605" data
), `project.dataset.anotherTable` AS (
  SELECT 2435034 account, 'D1' name UNION ALL
  SELECT 1483528, 'D2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1010203, 'D3' 
)
SELECT 
  STRING_AGG(nbr, '|' ORDER BY pos) account_nbr,
  STRING_AGG(name, '|' ORDER BY pos) account_name,  
  data
FROM `project.dataset.yourTable` t, 
UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(REGEXP_REPLACE(t.data, r'[^\d]+', ','),r'[0-9]{7}')) nbr WITH OFFSET pos
JOIN `project.dataset.anotherTable` x
ON CAST(x.account AS STRING) = nbr
GROUP BY data
```

> Update for new question in comments: records are getting filtered if t.data is null. Is there a way i can get the records even t.data is null? In my table some of the records doesnt have value for t.data

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.yourTable` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, ";2435031;1;5.98;;eVar36=bopis|ev2=2605,;1483528;1;17.97;;ev6=bopis|evar52=2605,;1010203;1;7.98;;ev6=bopis|ev2=2605" data UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, NULL
), `project.dataset.anotherTable` AS (
  SELECT 2435034 account, 'D1' name UNION ALL
  SELECT 1483528, 'D2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1010203, 'D3' 
)
SELECT 
  id, 
  (SELECT STRING_AGG(nbr, '|' ORDER BY pos) 
    FROM UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(
      REGEXP_REPLACE(t.data, r'[^\d]+', ','),r'[0-9]{7}')) nbr WITH OFFSET pos
    JOIN `project.dataset.anotherTable` x
      ON CAST(x.account AS STRING) = nbr
  ) a_nbr,
  (SELECT STRING_AGG(name, '|' ORDER BY pos) 
    FROM UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(
      REGEXP_REPLACE(t.data, r'[^\d]+', ','),r'[0-9]{7}')) nbr WITH OFFSET pos
    JOIN `project.dataset.anotherTable` x
      ON CAST(x.account AS STRING) = nbr
  ) a_name,
  data
FROM `project.dataset.yourTable` t
GROUP BY id, data
```

Comment: while i was answering - your comment with question got deleted. hope my update still will be useful for you :o)